# PostgreSQL multi-user

Tags: postgresql

I've a problem using 2 python scripts using PostgreSQL. Only the fist can work, the second obtain 'Database is locked' How to solve this problem?
Every script on start read data from tables and further only write data in 1 table. First script write one record in 1-30 minutes and the second script write constanlly.
I've try 2 python 3.10 script with PostgreSQL Please help me.
I've test add the FOR KEY SHARE for SELECT in both script - no effect Postgre locks not a table, but all database. Why?
I've tried differnt users for every scripts - no effect
Must I to create the third script with server functional and use PostrgeSQL only from this server-script and rebuild my current scripts for client tecnology not for use PostgreSQL?
It there any solution of this ?

Is this a bug or property of PostgreSQL or I do'nt know someting about it.

PostgreSQL 15.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Python 3.10

```
import psycopg2 as pg
...
    with pg.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                    port=5432,
                    user='postgres',
                    password='password',
                    database='database',
                ) as connection:
```

absolutely usual text. In any book present...
In both scripts present this code

```
import psycopg2 as pg
from pyrogram import Client, filters
...
with pg.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                port=5432,
                user='postgres',
                password='myPassword',
                database='myDatabase',
                ) as connection:
    read_lists_from_database(connection)
```

main function of script_1:

```
@app.on_message(filters.text)
async def wait_for_new_message(client, message):
    if message is None and client is None:
        return
    if not message.text is None:
        text = message.text.lower()
        finded = [phrase for phrase in phrases if text.find(phrase) > 0 or text.startswith(phrase)]
        finded_ban = [phrase for phrase in banned_phrases if text.find(phrase) > 0 or text.startswith(phrase)]
        info = message.from_user
        if len(finded) > 0 and not info.is_bot and len(finded_ban) == 0:
            finded_prases = ','.join(finded)
            info = message.from_user
            res_text = f'{finded_prases}:\n\r' \
                       f'{message.date} - {info.username} - {info.first_name}.{info.last_name} from ' \
                       f'{message.chat.title}:\n\r{text}\n\r' \
                       f'{message.text[:100]}'
            await store_message_in_database(message, client)
            print(f'\r\n{res_text}')
            await message.forward(target_bot)
        else:
            print(f'\r* {message.chat.title}', end="", flush=True)
    else:
        pass

async def store_message_in_database(message,client):
    with pg.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                    port=5432,
                    user='postgres',
                    password='myPassword',
                    database='myDatabase',
                ) as connection:
        cur = connection.cursor()
        info = message.from_user
        query = f"INSERT INTO target_messages VALUES(DEFAULT, '{message.text}','{info.username}', " \
                f"'{message.chat.title}, {message.id}')"
        cur.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
```

The second script scan the list of chanels and write all message in db:

def main():

```
app_py = Client('accaunt', app_id, app_hash)
num_channels = 1
delete_channels_due_400 = 0
pass_number = 1
with pg.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                    port=5432,
                    user='postgres',
                    password='myPassword',
                    database='myDatabase'
                    ) as connection:
    while True:
        read_lists_from_database(connection)
        start = time.time()
        for channel in source_channels:
            result = scan_chanel_deep(app_py, channel, num_channels)
            delete_chanels_due_400 = (delete_chanels_due_400 + 1) 
            if not result else delete_chanels_due_400
            fix_channel_in_database(connection, channel)
            num_channels += 1
            if num_channels % 100 == 0:
               app_py = Client('accaunt', app_id, app_hash)
               print(f'I'm sleeping {config.time_out_every_100} sec.')
               sleep(config.time_out_every_100)
            else:
                sleep(config.timeout)
        end = time.time()
        print(f'=========== Pass {pass_number} ==============')
        print(f'On pass {first_time_len} channels elapsed {end-start/3600:.4} hour.')
```

And every time I run script_2 I've got the error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked. Even I run script_2 first and script_1 some time later, the script_1 working and script_2 get error sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
Why databse is locked? Who lock it?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the script, postgresql-version.

Comment: Is this information enough

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't lock a table for writing data. It might lock a record for update, but not for inserts. And you didn't share the scripts you're testing, hard to help you.

Comment: There are no database locks in PostgreSQL, and the error message comes from somewhere else. Are you trying to run two statements concurrently on the same database session?

Comment: To your question add the complete error/traceback message.

Comment: File "progNamepy", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "ProgName.py", line 202, in main
    result = scan_chanel_deep(app_py, channel, num_chanels)
  File "ProgName.py", line 91, in scan_chanel_deep
    with app_py:
    return self.conn.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is lockedline 
    app_py = Client('accaunt', app_id, app_hash)

Comment: 1) As requested add to question as update, not in comments. 2) This `sqlite3.OperationalError:` was not a hint? You are connecting to wrong database.

Comment: from pyrogram import Client
import psycopg2 as pg both

app_py = Client('accaunt', app_id, app_hash)

File "progName.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "ProgName.py", line 202, in main
    result = scan_chanel_deep(app_py, channel, num_chanels)
  File "ProgName.py", line 91, in scan_chanel_deep
    with app_py:
    return self.conn.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
I recive this error only when another script running with the same strings
from pyrogram import Client

@app.on_message(filters.text)
async def wait_for_new_message(client, message):

Comment: What part of `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked` is unclear? The locking and the error is coming from a connection to a SQLite3 database. This is not a Postgres issue.  Since you don't show an explicit SQLite3 connection I'm going to guess it is implied in `app_py = Client('accaunt', app_id, app_hash)`. You will need to track that down on your end.

Comment: But from where SQLite 3 ???? if in me code
import psycopg2 as pg and future with pg.connect() I've never use SQLite in this project. Where can be the bug ? In Sqlite I've never create the base with the same name, as it is in my project. MyDbname = LegendTeam_lead and I create it only in PgAdmin4. What the hell ?

Comment: It seems I've understand - this is the problem of pyrogram. For some itself needs it uses SQLite. I don't want  ti fix pyrogram functional
My question is closed. Thanks for allbody.

Comment: Read this [pyrogram database locked](https://docs.pyrogram.org/faq/sqlite3-operationalerror-database-is-locked). You should also read [Storage Engines](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/storage-engines).